# Show that a linear transformation

Tags: real-analysis

Show that a linear transformation .$A:{R^n} \to {R^m}$. with $m \times n$ matrix $[{a_{ij}}]$ can be written As 
$A = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^m {\sum\limits_{j = 1}^n {{a_{ij}}} } {\varepsilon _i}{\pi _j}$.

Which 
${\pi _j}({x_1},{x_2},...,{x_n}) = {x_j}$  , ${\varepsilon _i}(t) = t{e_i}$

I try to do it , but it hard for me . please help me. for begin to do it.

Comment: what are $\epsilon_i$ and $\pi_j$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $x \in \mathbb R^n$, then $A$, by definition of the representing matrix, we have 
$$ (Ax)_i = \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_j $$
for $i \le m$, on the other hand
\begin{align*}
  Ax &= \sum_{i=1}^m (Ax)_i e_i\\
     &= \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} e_i x_j\\
     &= \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} \epsilon_i(x_j)\\
     &= \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} \epsilon_i\pi_j(x) 
\end{align*}
As $x \in \mathbb R^n$ was arbitrary 
$$ A= \sum_{i,j} a_{ij} \epsilon_i \pi_j $$

Comment: thank for solution . thank you very much.